# css overrides php for unknown reason

Tags: php, html, css, cookies

For some reason in the following code, cookies are not set on the login screen if the indicated lines in the css exist. Similar behavior can be seen with other css elements too. I have been at this for 3 days now and can not figure out why.

For those testing, the username is 'test' and the password is 'debug'

All help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php

$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
  'test' => 'debug'
);

// time out after NN minutes of inactivity. Set to 0 to not timeout
define('TIMEOUT_MINUTES', 10);

define('TIMEOUT_CHECK_ACTIVITY', true);

$GLOBALS['programname'] = "Testing";



            define('LOGOUT_URL', 'test.php');
            define('USE_USERNAME', true);
            $timeout = (TIMEOUT_MINUTES == 0 ? 0 : time() + 
TIMEOUT_MINUTES * 60);
            if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
                setcookie("verify", '', $timeout, '/'); // clear 
password;
                header('Location: ' . LOGOUT_URL);
                exit();
            }
            if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
                $usr= $_COOKIE['user'];
            }
        ?>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik" 
rel="stylesheet">
        <style>

label, p, a, h1, h2, h3, th, input{
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}
h1.header{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:55px;
}
div.navigation{
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height:30px;
}
div.nav{
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
}
div.nav p{
    margin:auto;
    transform: translateY(40%);
}
span.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
body{
    margin:40px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-width:795px;
}
form, h1, table{
    margin: 10px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
    empty-cells: show;
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
th:first-child, table td.line:nth-child(2){
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
th:last-child, table td.line:last-child{
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
div.img { 
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
div.img img{
    width: 20vw;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a p{
    margin-left:10px;
}
a:hover p{
    color:#33cc33;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
p.img:hover{
    color:#33cc33;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover div.img { 
    display: block;
}
td.line1{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
label{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
}
div.form-group{
    display: inline-block;
}
table td.line:last-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
}
td.line{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=date], 
input[type=number], input[type=file], select {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
input[type=submit], input[type=button]{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}
select{
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   overflow: hidden;
}
select select {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 29px;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 268px;
}
p.small{
    font-size:15px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
input.red{
    background-color: #CF0000;
}
input.red:hover{
    background-color: #Bd0000;
}
div.border{
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
.border, .fadeonce, .img{
    animation: fadein 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
    -o-animation: fadein 1s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        max-height:1px;
        overflow: hidden;                       /*   DELETE THIS LINE 
TO SEE EXPECTED BEHAVIOR */
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        max-height:100%;
        overflow: hidden;                       /*   DELETE THIS LINE 
TO SEE EXPECTED BEHAVIOR */
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        max-height:1px;
        overflow: hidden;                       /*   DELETE THIS LINE 
TO SEE EXPECTED BEHAVIOR */
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        max-height:100%;
        overflow: hidden;                       /*   DELETE THIS LINE 
TO SEE EXPECTED BEHAVIOR */
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        max-height:1px;
        overflow: hidden;                       /*   DELETE THIS LINE 
TO SEE EXPECTED BEHAVIOR */
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        max-height:100%;
        overflow: hidden;                       /*   DELETE THIS LINE 
TO SEE EXPECTED BEHAVIOR */
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
        max-height:1px;
        overflow: hidden;                       /*   DELETE THIS LINE 
TO SEE EXPECTED BEHAVIOR */
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        max-height:100%;
        overflow: hidden;                       /*   DELETE THIS LINE 
TO SEE EXPECTED BEHAVIOR */

    }
}

        </style>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
        <?php
            if(!function_exists('showLoginPasswordProtect')) {
                // show login form
                function showLoginPasswordProtect($error_msg) {
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1 class="header"><?php echo $GLOBALS['programname']; ?>
</h1>
        </center>
        <br>
        <div style="width:500px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; 
text-align:center">
            <div class="border">
                <form method="post">
                    <h2>Please enter your password</h2>
                    <font color="red"><?php echo $error_msg; ?>
</font><br />
                    <?php if (USE_USERNAME) echo '<p>Login:</p><input 
type="text" name="access_login" /><p>Password: </p>'; ?>
                    <input type="password" name="access_password" />
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" 
/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
                    // stop at this point
                    die();
                }
            }
            // user provided password
            if (isset($_POST['access_password'])) {
                $login = isset($_POST['access_login']) ? 
$_POST['access_login'] : '';
                $pass = $_POST['access_password'];
                if (!USE_USERNAME && !in_array($pass, 
$LOGIN_INFORMATION) || (USE_USERNAME && ( !array_key_exists($login, 
$LOGIN_INFORMATION) || $LOGIN_INFORMATION[$login] != $pass ))){
                    showLoginPasswordProtect("Incorrect password.");
                }else{
                    // set cookie if password was validated
                    setcookie("verify", md5($login.'%'.$pass), 
$timeout, '/');
                    setcookie("user", $login, $timeout, '/');
                    $usr = $login;                                              
                    unset($_POST['access_login']);
                    unset($_POST['access_password']);
                    unset($_POST['Submit']);
                }
            }else{
                // check if password cookie is set 
                if (!isset($_COOKIE['verify'])) {
                    showLoginPasswordProtect("");
                }
                // check if cookie is good
                $found = false;
                foreach($LOGIN_INFORMATION as $key=>$val) {
                    $lp = (USE_USERNAME ? $key : '') .'%'.$val;
                    if ($_COOKIE['verify'] == md5($lp)) {
                        $found = true;
                        // prolong timeout
                        if (TIMEOUT_CHECK_ACTIVITY) {
                            setcookie("verify", md5($lp), $timeout, 
'/');
                            setcookie("user", $usr, $timeout, '/');
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!$found) {
                    showLoginPasswordProtect("");
                }
            } 
        ?>

    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1 class="header"><?php echo $GLOBALS['programname']; ?>
</h1>
        </center>
        <br>
        <div class="navigation  <?php if ($_GET['page'] == "") {echo 
' fadeonce';}?>">
            <div class="nav"></div>
            <a href="?page=1">
                <div class="nav">
                    <p>test1</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="?page=2">
                <div class="nav">
                    <p>test2</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="?page=3">
                <div class="nav">
                    <p>test3</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="?page=4">
                <div class="nav">
                    <p>test4</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="?page=0">
                <div class="nav">
                    <p>test0</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="?logout=1">
                <div class="nav">
                    <p>Logout <?php echo $usr;?></p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="nav"></div>
            <span class="stretch"></span>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div class="border" <?php if ($_GET['page'] != "0") {echo 
'style="display: none;"';}?>>
            <h1>Test 0</h1>
            <p>this is a test page</p>
        </div>

        <div class="border" <?php if ($_GET['page'] != "1") {echo 
'style="display: none;"';}?>>
            <h1>Test 1</h1>
            <p>this is a test page</p>
        </div>

        <div class="border" <?php if ($_GET['page'] != "2") {echo 
'style="display: none;"';}?>>
            <h1>Test 2</h1>
            <p>this is a test page</p>
        </div>

        <div class="border" <?php if ($_GET['page'] != "3") {echo 
'style="display: none;"';}?>>
            <h1>Test 3</h1>
            <p>this is a test page</p>
        </div>

        <div class="border" <?php if ($_GET['page'] != "4") {echo 
'style="display: none;"';}?>>
            <h1>Test 4</h1>
            <p>this is a test page</p>
        </div>

        <div  <?php if ($_GET['page'] == "") {echo 
'class="fadeonce"';}?>>
            <p><b>Footer Text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't send cookies, if the header is already sent - so `setcookie` has to be called, before you output anything (in your case, the setcookie code has to be called before <html>)

Comment: if that had been a reply, i would have marked it as the answer. thank you so much for your help. i dont know how that slid past me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think this has something todo with the css code. The problem might be, that you can't send cookies, after the header was already sent.

In your case, you have to put the `setcookie` code before `<html>`

```
<?php
// ...
setcookie(...);
//...
?>
<html>
    <head>
    ...
```